# How to exclude Jars from being added in the WAR file

Tags: java, eclipse, jar, war

In the my application I have set some jars as project dependency. This jars are added as User Library. As I am running the application in JBoss AS7 and I am using the JSF implementation which is provided by the JBoss server, I have copied those JSF jars from the module and create a new User Library namely JBoss JSF. This library has been used to create JSF 2 Dynamic Web Project in Eclipse. Now when I am exporting it as a WAR file, those jsf jars are automatically being copied and added in `/WEB-INF/lib` of the war. I don't want that these files are added as they are already present in the container.

Is there any way to do it?

For more information, this is the content of the .classpath file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<classpath>
    <classpathentry kind="src" path="src/common"/>
    <classpathentry kind="src" path="src/service"/>
    <classpathentry kind="src" path="src/web"/>
    <classpathentry kind="src" path="src/persistent"/>
    <classpathentry kind="src" path="src/dao"/>
    <classpathentry kind="con" path="org.eclipse.jdt.launching.JRE_CONTAINER/org.eclipse.jdt.internal.debug.ui.launcher.StandardVMType/jre7">
        <attributes>
            <attribute name="owner.project.facets" value="java"/>
        </attributes>
    </classpathentry>
    <classpathentry kind="con" path="org.eclipse.jst.j2ee.internal.web.container"/>
    <classpathentry kind="con" path="org.eclipse.jst.j2ee.internal.module.container"/>
    <classpathentry kind="con" path="org.eclipse.jdt.USER_LIBRARY/JBoss JSF">
        <attributes>
            <attribute name="owner.project.facets" value="jst.jsf"/>
        </attributes>
    </classpathentry>
    <classpathentry kind="con" path="org.eclipse.jdt.USER_LIBRARY/JBoss Servlet"/>
    <classpathentry kind="con" path="org.eclipse.jdt.USER_LIBRARY/JBoss log4j"/>
    <classpathentry kind="output" path="build/classes"/>
</classpath>
```

The Deployment Assembly of my application:
[image]

Comment: @Rahul I have seen this link before, the solution there provide a way to exclude files from the source tab.

Comment: +1 for suggestion on ant (even if the question is "eclipse based")

Comment: @acostache Right, but let's consider that ant integration in Eclipse has been present for a long time and works pretty well. Moreover Eclipse native export wizard IMHO has always been a pain to use, not enough flexible for my needs.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this

1. Open Project properties
2. Select Deployment Assembly
3. Select libraries that you need to exclude from the war file then click Remove . 
   Jars you selected will be removed from the War file

or try to add one more attribute to the .classpath file

```
<classpathentry kind="con" path="org.eclipse.jdt.USER_LIBRARY/JBoss JSF">

   <attributes>

    <attribute name="owner.project.facets" value="jst.jsf"/>

    <attribute name="org.eclipse.jst.component.nondependency" value=""/> 

  </attributes>
```

Comment: Rahul I have added an image of the Deployment Assembly. There no jars.

Comment: Can you please try to add one more attribute to the .classpath file

<classpathentry kind="con" path="org.eclipse.jdt.USER_LIBRARY/JBoss JSF">

<attributes>

<attribute name="owner.project.facets" value="jst.jsf"/>

<attribute name="org.eclipse.jst.component.nondependency" value=""/> 

</attributes>

</classpathentry>

Answer (score 0):

1. Open the Project Properties Dialog.
2. Select Java Build Path  from the left panel.
3. Select Source Tab.
4. A list of all Jars included in the project will be listed.
5. Select the JAR file and click edit button.
6. In the included or excluded pattern window, choose excluded (If that's what you want) and add a pattern. Select Ok.
7. In each row of the jar's, at the right hand side you will see a plus or minus sign accordingly.

Comment: Thanks, but I am sorry, in the Source tab there is only the list of all source files. There is no such list of jars. The jars files are listed in the Libraries.

Comment: Try de-selecting the unwanted libraries in Order and Export tab.

Comment: I have tried this option. The libraries are there but they are not checked.

Comment: I have added the content of the classpath in the question

Comment: I don't want to "answer" the question by suggesting a different tool, but Apache Maven really does excel at solving these kind of fine-grained build requirements. But even ANT could already be a step in the right direction. You don't want to fiddle with your IDE to create deployments, you want to have a reliable and reproducible solution.

Answer (score 0):

you can set the scope of the dependency to provided. ndicates you expect the JDK or a container to provide the dependency at runtime. For example, when building a web application for the Java Enterprise Edition, you would set the dependency on the Servlet API and related Java EE APIs to scope provided because the web container provides those classes. This scope is only available on the compilation and test classpath, and is not transitive.  A dependency with this scope will not be included in wars/ears.

```
 <dependency>
        <groupId>javax.mail</groupId>
        <artifactId>mail</artifactId>
        <version>1.4</version>
        <scope>provided</scope>
    </dependency>
```