# Removing a JAR from deployment

Tags: spring, jboss, ear

I am working on a Spring Project on a JBoss server. I am facing a [situation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24384252/retrieving-native-connection-from-jboss-wrapped-connection) where I think removing a jar from the deployment may solve all the issues. But I want to keep the JAR in compile time so that I can use it in the classes.

I want to know how I can remove a jar from deployment only but keep it during the run time.

Probably, this is not the question to be asked on SO, as a matter of fact, SO is all about Coders and its main intention is to help us in solving a problem.

So, anyone ? How I can do this ?

Comment: What build tool are you using? Maven, Ant or IDE based?

Comment: I am using Eclipse which is I think IDE based.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you are using Maven, the you need to mark the dependency as `provided`.

For example

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>log4j</groupId>
    <artifactId>log4j</artifactId>
    <version>1.2.17</version>
    <scope>provided</scope>
</dependency>
```

If you are using Gradle the corresponding element would be `providedCompile`. The code would look like:

```
providedCompile 'log4j:log4j:1.2.17'
```

For an Eclipse based build, check out [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13950012/how-to-exclude-jars-from-being-added-in-the-war-file) SO post

Comment: Can you provide method for eclipse ?

Comment: Right now. I am away from my PC. I will accept your answer as soon as I try mentioned method.

Thanks.

Comment: No problem! Hope it helps!